# SQL Server rounding issue on insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an application that computes a value of -1407.858; the C# data type for this is `decimal`.

The column data type in the database is decimal(12,2). I would've thought it'd round the value and insert -1407.86 (which would satisfy both away from zero rounding and to even rounding).

Unfortunately the value is being inserted as -1407.85. The only explanation I can come up for this is that the last digit is being truncated.

I have done some simple test queries in SQL Server such as:

```
declare @first AS decimal(12,2)
declare @second AS float --[or decimal(12,3)]

set @second = -1407.858
set @first=@second

select @first;
```

And I get back -1407.86, so I suppose SQL Server automatically rounds values when it's setting them, but not when inserting them. Is this correct? Does SQL Server only truncate when inserting, but round when setting?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Yes, it rounds values to two decimals when you put it in a variable with two decimals.

Comment: @Harry and the question is... ? :)

Comment: @Harry, how are you inserting this value? Are you using linq2sql, ef, or any data framework?

Comment: @JNK I'm wondering why it's being truncated and not rounded.

Comment: Don't bother "fighting" it, use the ROUND function on your result before inserting it. That way you can explicitly round using the method of your choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test with Linq2sql, with the following situation:

- Mapped a table with a int primary key, and a decimal(12,2) field;
- Inserted a item with the value -12.585;

Executing SQL Profiler, I realized linq2sql has truncated the value, sending the following statement to server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestNumbers]([Id], [Number1])
VALUES (@p0, @p1)',N'@p0 int,@p1 decimal(12,2)',@p0=0,@p1=-12.58
```

So you are facing a linq2sql bug. You should round your numbers before you send them.

Comment: Could it be that Linq2sql was using even rounding? Have you tested it with the OP's value?

Comment: Thanks, that's where my thoughts were heading too.

Comment: @AndriyM I tried it with a number of values and they were all truncated, not rounded (in any form).

Answer (score 2):

> I suppose SQL Server automatically rounds values when it's setting
>   them, but not when inserting them. Is this correct?

Nope.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(C DECIMAL(12,2))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (-1407.858)
SELECT * FROM @T
```

Returns `-1407.86`. I presume the truncation happens somewhere on the `C#` side.

Answer (score 0):

A `decimal(12,2)` can store 12 digits total, of which two are behind the comma.  So it's correct that `-1407.858` is rounded to `-1407.85`.

Comment: I *think* the question is why it's TRUNCated and not ROUNDed.  But the best answer I can think of is "because it is", or maybe "because that's what the documentation says it should do".

Comment: @Andomar, the correct rounded value (as a decimal(12,2)) for -1407.858 is -1407.86.

Comment: @Dems If the answer is simply "that's what the documentation says it should do" - great; but where does it say that?